# Как сделать так чтобы блоки становились друг под другом

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

верстаю на flex, при justify-content: space-between;  нижние блоки разъезжаются. Так вот вопрос, как их выровнять ровненько друг под другом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставьте space-evenly

Comment: не работает, становятся как при space-around

Comment: Если бы Вы скинули разметку и стили, было бы проще

Comment: там заказчик уже передумал так делать) Уже не надо, спасибо